# fetched the value from controller in service

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, service, controller

I want to get the value fetched in service which is passed in the controller and pass it to the php page. The `$scope.Album` value is pushed from the controller. Now I get it and load in local storage in service in var `get_save_album`. I want to fetch it directly without local storage and it to php page.

controller.js:

```
$scope.savealbum = function () {
  $scope.getAlbum = AlbumServices.get_album();
  $scope.Album = {
    .... value....
  };
  if ($scope.getAlbum === null) {
    $scope.initalPush.push($scope.Album);
    AlbumServices.save_album($scope.initalPush);
  } else {
    $scope.getAlbum.push($scope.Album);
    AlbumServices.save_album($scope.getAlbum);
  }
  alert('Album Added Successfully');
  $location.path('/album_list');
};
```

JavaScript:

```
get_album: function () {
  var get_save_album = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('album'));
  $http.post('js/data/album.php',get_save_album)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config)
    {
      console.log(status + ' - ' + data);                 
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config)
    {                   
      console.log('error');
    });

  return get_save_album;
}
```